# Cocos2D multiple touches on multiple CCMenu

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I am making head-to-head game using `Cocos2D 2.1`. So I've created to CCMenu on both sides. The game may require independent handling of both menus. However, when one is tapped, the second one is ignored. Any solution how to handle both touches at the same time with `CCMenu`?

Comment: multi touch enabled? If so and the issue persists scrap ccmenu

Comment: `[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES]` helped, thanks